# Button - Using a button to make a rectangle bigger

Tags: javascript, button, raphael

I'm a newbie computer coder and I'm taking an introductory class on HTML, CSS, Javascript and Raphael.

I'm doing an assignment where I'm supposed to use a button to make a rectangle bigger (rec1) and I'm stumped on this part (I'm using HTML and Raphael for this assignment).

To give some context, I'm using Raphael to make a snowman with a hat. When I click the button, the hat (rec1) should get bigger.

I've copied and pasted the assignment instructions below:

> Add a  element below the SVG (as examples from previous exercises have had). When the button is clicked, the hat (or at least some part of it) should get bigger.
>
> To do this, you'll need to save the rectangle in a variable when it is created
>
> hat = paper.rect(...)
>   And then when the button is clicked, use the .scale() function to scale it horizontally and/or vertically:
>
> hat.scale(1.1, 1.0)

Here is my HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

<script src="http://cmpt165.csil.sfu.ca/js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://cmpt165.csil.sfu.ca/js/raphael-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="my-code.js"></script>

 <title>Raphael Test</title>
</head>

<body>
 <h1>Raphael Snowman</h1>
  <div id="container" align='center'></div>
  <button id="hat"></button>


 
</body>

</html>
```

And here is my javascript coding.

```js
length = 20;

increaseLength = function(){
 length += 10;
}



setup = function() {
  paper = Raphael('container', 300, 300)
  rec1 = paper.rect(40,10,length,15)
  rec1.attr({
 'fill': 'black',
 'stroke': '#000',
 'stroke-width': '2'
  })
  rec2 = paper.rect(30,25,40,10)
  rec2.attr({
 'fill': 'black',
 'stroke': '#000',
 'stroke-width': '2'
  })
  circ1 = paper.circle(50, 60, 24)
  circ1.attr({
    'stroke': '#000',
    'stroke-width': '2'
  })
  circ2 = paper.circle(50, 90, 28)
  circ2.attr({
    'stroke': '#000',
    'stroke-width': '2'
  })
  circ3 = paper.circle(50, 130, 32)
  circ3.attr({
    'stroke': '#000',
    'stroke-width': '2'
  })
}
```

Comment: Where do you add any event calls from the button? I'm not sure what your expectations are. If you could provide a working snippet of what you currently have that would be great. If it helps you can link direct to the libraries over **https** for the snippets to work on stackoverflow `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.4/raphael.js`

Comment: Thank you for replying NewToJS. I probably haven't explained myself very well. Again, I'm new to coding and JavaScript has been quite challenging for me. Here's a link to my assignment, hope fully it'll give you a better idea of what I need: https://coursys.sfu.ca/2017fa-cmpt-165-c0/pages/Exercise8

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add an event listener to the button (click event) and also a function to scale the hat up. Please don't use jQuery and ignore any answer that tells you to - plain JavaScript is fine.

Look at the Mozilla Developer JavaScript reference to start - it's an excellent resource for learning the 'right way' to write JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

You can add a click handler to the button with...

```
<button id="hat" onclick="hatBigger()">Click me</button>
```

And a global function that it can call with...

```
window.hatBigger = function() {
  hat1.transform('s2')
  hat2.transform('s2')
}
```

We can simply use a variable to save this (that is outside the function scope)

```
var hat1; // global scope
```

then later on in the setup

```
hat1 = rec1;
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wkvme3v1/4/)

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code Ian and I was able to expand my hat. The first time around I missed some of the coding, but I corrected the work later on. Thanks for the help!

I realize now how much more I need to learn about JavaScript and Raphael, so I'm trying to review my study guide.